# C# Winform How to Pin/UnPin WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a web browser control embedded in a tabPage in my application. How do I drag it out of my desktop app, that is an option to dock/undock or unpin it.

Edit: After reading a bit, I think I should do this with DragDrop events. I saw several examples to drag and drop within an application or between applications, but I am wondering if it is possible to drag the control outside my application to another screen. Should I record the screen coordinates to do this?

Edit: So far I have tried to capture MouseUp/MouseDown events with a simple button control but that only helps with moving the control within the form.

When I was reading DragDrop documentation in MSDN, it says 'AllowDrop' needs to be set to the target. But my target is not limited to a form it can also be a desktop screen. It makes me think I am totally on the wrong route.  I am not pasting any code because I believe I am looking for an approach or some suggestion to do this. I am a novice so if this is not clear, please ask me further questions.

Hoping to hear from someone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, this codeproject link helped me get started:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15418/PullApartTabPage-Docking-and-Undocking-Your-TabPag